# Removing system-wide git repos and git checkouts that Bundler may use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, bundler

In my gem file I have a Git reference:

```
gem "calendar_date_select", :git => 'git://github.com/paneq/calendar_date_select.git'
```

I would like to know where bundler paced that Git checkout so I can manually clean it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this depends on your local setup. let me explain by one of my projects.

it's within an rvm gemset, so my `.rvmrc` is like this:

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p125@hamburg_on_ruby --install --create
```

and i use ActiveAdmin from git in my `Gemfile`

```
gem "activeadmin", :git => "https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git"
```

which results in a `Gemfile.lock` like this

```
GIT
  remote: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git
  revision: 82a13de45feeba2510f015aaae9d412878e4c6f5
```

so the actual cloned repo is in

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@hamburg_on_ruby/bundler/gems/active_admin-82a13de45fee/
```